# RegExp doesn't match when in the middle of other words

Tags: c, regex, lex

Hello everyone I'm testing a regexp with lex to find the product id in html from amazon. I don't know why when it read the file witch contains:

```
<span class="a-icon-alt">4,7 de un máximo de 5 estrellas</span>
```

it works but if it content is something like:

aaaaaa< span class="a-icon-alt">4,7 de un máximo de 5 estrellas< /span>bbbbbb

it doesnt. There is the code with regex.

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>

int nc, np, nl;
void escribir_datos (int dato1, int dato2, int dato3);
%}

productos (<li+[ ]+id=\"result_[0-9]*)+
num_productos [0-9]*
nombre_producto <h2+[ ]+data-attribute=\"([^\"]*)
nombre_final_producto \"[^\"]*\"
precio_producto <span+[ ]+class=\"a-size-base+[ ]+a-color-price+[ ]+s-price+[ ]+a-text-bold\">(.*?)<\/span>
precio_final_producto [0-9]+([,][0-9]+)?
valoraciones  <span+[ ]+class=\"a-icon-alt\">(.*?)<\/span>

%%

{valoraciones}    { nl++; }
[^ \t\n]+   { np++; nc += yyleng; }
[ \t]+      { nc += yyleng; }
\n          { nc++; }
%%

/*----- Sección de Procedimientos --------*/

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc == 2) {
     yyin = fopen (argv[1], "rt");
     if (yyin == NULL) {
         printf ("El fichero %s no se puede abrir\n", argv[1]);
         exit (-1);
     }
  }
  else yyin = stdin;

nc = np = nl = 0;
yylex ();
escribir_datos(nc,np,nl);

return 0;
}

void escribir_datos (int dato1, int dato2, int dato3) {
printf("Num_char=%d\tNum_words=%d\tNum_lines=%d\n", dato1,dato2,dato3);
}
```

Thanks I hope you can help me.

Comment: Why did you tag it as c++?

Answer (score 1):

The intended use case for lexical analyzers generated by (f)lex is to split the input into a series of primitive "tokens", each one with some syntactic significance. They do not *search* for regular expressions, because they assume that every part of the input will match some pattern in your lexical description.

So each time the lexical analyzer examines the input, it will select the pattern which gives the best *match*. A match is a sequence of characters starting at the current input point which matches a pattern, and the best match is the one which matches the longest sequence. (If there are two or more patterns which match the same longest sequence, the first one in the list of patterns is considered the best one.)

With that in mind, consider what happens with the input

```
aaaaaa< span class="a-icon-alt">4,7 de un máximo de 5 estrellas< /span>bbbbbb
```

Your file has four patterns:

```
{valoraciones}
[^ \t\n]+
[ \t]+
\n
```

The input doesn't match `{valoraciones}` because that pattern only matches a string starting with <kbd><</kbd>. It doesn't match `[ \t]+` either, because it doesn't start with either space or tab, and similarly it doesn't match a newline. But it does match `[^ \t\n]+`. Since (f)lex always select the longest match, and `[^ \t\n]+` matches any sequence of characters other than whitespace (space, tab, newline), the first match will be `aaaaaaa<`.

After that's matched, the input is `span...`, which means that only the third pattern (`[ \t]+`) matches. It could match any number of space characters, but there is only one and that's what it will match.

So then the input is `span class="a-icon-alt">4,7...`. `{valoraciones}` still won't match -- the input doesn't start with <kbd><</kbd> -- so we're back to a match of the second pattern.

And so on.

I think you need to be a lot clearer (with yourself) about what the *tokens* you are trying to match are. If you're looking for specific HTML tags, then you probably want to recognise any sequence which doesn't contain a <kbd><</kbd> as a token, rather than looking for input terminated with a white space character. But then you also need to accept any tag as a token, as well as the specific tags you are trying to catch.

Of course, it is also possible that (f)lex is not the ideal tool for your use case. You don't really say what your use case it, so I'm not going to make any assumption one way or another.

In any event, you should take a few minutes to read the [documentation on flex patterns](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html). Any regex syntax not described on that page will not work with (f)lex, regardless of whether it works with regex libraries or online regex checkers. In particular, `.*?` does *not* give you a non-greedy match, as it would in many regex libraries. (F)lex doesn't implement non-greedy matches (because it doesn't do any backtracking), and it considers `.*?` to be an optional (`?`) appearance of any number including zero repetitions (`*`) of any character other than a newline (`.`). Making the repetition optional has no effect, since the repetition already matches zero repetitions. So the pattern `<.*?>` would match from the <kbd><</kbd> up to the last <kbd>></kbd> on the same line. That is probably not what you want.

You also probably don't want `<span+`, which matches <kbd><</kbd> followed by the letters <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> and then any number of <kbd>n</kbd> (as long as there is at least one). In other words, it will match `<span`, `<spann`, `<spannnnnnnnnnn`, and many more.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer, the problem was the three rules after {valoraciones} caused conflict with the first one. So i couldn't find any  word between other words for example, I want to find dog in a text with aaaaadogaaaa, that doesn't match with dog cause of what i said at the beginning.